# Where can I find a chart of education level by political party?

Tags: united-states, parties, education, political-spectrum, demographics

It must include libertarian, democrat, and republican. I tried to find one on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=political%20ideology%20education&tbs=imgo:1#tbs=imgo:1&tbm=isch&q=%20education%20level%20libertarian%20political%20party&imgrc=_), but could not.

An acceptable alternative is IQ by political party.

I found libertarian education statistics in a [report from Reason Magazine](http://reason.com/assets/db/14824159478653.pdf), but it doesn't compare with liberals or conservatives, and could possibly be biased.

Comment: Do you mean party membership; or voting for specific party?

Comment: Related question at skeptics (see also the other linked questions there): [Do non-educated people tend more to the right/conservative political wing?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14983/do-non-educated-people-tend-more-to-the-right-conservative-political-wing)

Comment: [related](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/507/in-the-u-s-are-people-with-more-education-more-likely-to-vote-liberal)

Comment: Party membership. The others are not related as they do not include libertarian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quick look around, as you did, but I couldn't find a chart which included the Libertarian Party. Nevertheless, we can use data from the [Cooperative Congressional Election Study 2018](https://cces.gov.harvard.edu/) to produce one. After weighting the raw data to be representative of the registered voter population, we are left with a dataset which provides education data for just over 10,000 Democrats, around 8,000 Republicans, and 130 Libertarians, as validated by Catalist. It is up to the reader whether this is a large enough sample on the Libertarian side of things for this data to be meaningful.

Using this data, we can produce the following chart, indicating the percentage of individuals registered to each party at that level of education.

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Any idea of margin of error? Could presumably be estimated using the variance across regions. I would guess that the variations are not statistically meaningful.