# Are people in hard science major more likely to be conservative rather than liberal?

Tags: ideology

This question ask if more educated people are liberal
[In the U.S., are people with more education more likely to vote liberal?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/507/in-the-u-s-are-people-with-more-education-more-likely-to-vote-liberal?rq=1)

A comment asks if people in hard science majors are more likely to be liberal.

That's what I am asking.

I have heard that programmers tend to be libertarians and engineers are less liberal.

Perhaps those who study women studies will be very progressive.

How true is that?

Comment: It’s unclear which comparison you’re asking about. Is it hard sciences vs social sciences? Hard sciences vs the public at large? Political leaning within hard sciences? Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm not clear on whether you are asking about those people with a degree in science. (most of whom won't be "scientists") or restricted to those people who are doing scientific research.  Also, what is the base-line?  Are you comparing the group with US average, or with an average for a demographically matched group (eg matched for age/race/economic status)

Comment: It's difficult to answer, you may find a lot of examples of highly liberal contexts or go to the extreme opposite citing the Chicago boys.

Comment: Money talks. The programmers thrive on social-economic "changes", while engineers are more reluctant and skeptical about any change, at least in the initial stage.

Comment: The question really doesn't work unless you define what you mean by liberal and conservative.  For instance, you say programmers tend to be libertarian (which from my own limited observation seems to be true of STEM generally), but do you consider that liberal or conservative?

Comment: It's hardly defined. I would say libertarian and conservative will more likely to vote republican instead of democrat in US

Comment: Looking at the question and the comments the OP left on my answer, this seems less like an earnest question than a bit of feminism bashing (e.g., the assertion that  *"feminazis will not admit they are fascist that want to enslave the rest of the world and start word war 3"*). I've added a close vote on principle, and left the comments un-flagged for the moment just so people can verify that I'm not making this up.

Comment: more likely than what? Having any degree is an increasingly accurate predictor of being liberal; sort the states by % w/degree and you get a pretty close approximation of the presidential returns in terms of rank. Ag, econ, and commerce are the more conservative fields, but they will still be more liberal (on avg) than someone w/no degree.

Answer (score 4):

The academic world cultivates independent thinking, careful analytic reasoning, and a willingness to challenge authoritative claims in the interests of the advancement of human knowledge. These qualities do not always sit well with conservative worldviews, since the latter demand some measure of unquestioning respect for traditional social orders, religious tenets, or implicit cultural norms. Conservatives in academia are generally more moderate than conservatives in the greater world, and always take a more sophisticated and nuanced perspective on conservative values.

People in the physical and mechanical sciences more or less reflect the political distribution of the communities they are drawn from, though they are less likely than the general population to take extreme views. Anything that demands obedience to authority, adherence to doctrine, or blind acceptance of received knowledge rubs the wrong way against the academic mindset. People in the social sciences and humanities — along with certain human-adjacent physical sciences, like evolutionary biology and climate science — tend to lean Left, because their subject matter explicitly calls on them to examine and critique human traditions, norms, and/or behaviors. Few people enter the social sciences with the preconception that the world is just peachy as it is, and that all we need is more of the same. Academia as a whole tends to be slightly left of center: uncomfortable with staunch, inflexible conservative norms and unwilling to engage liberal activism wholeheartedly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about academic standards in humanities has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128020/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-wrigley-are-people-in-hard-science-major-more-likely).